# Creating a Testimonials Content Type and making it work as it should

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a **Testimonials content type** which asks for a visitor's name and testimonial. Is it possible to make this form available to *Anonymous users* so anyone can post a testimonial without having to register?

I don't want people going through the Admin theme so I'm guessing I'll have to create my own form in the standard theme but how do I connect that to the actual Content Type? Posts must also *not* be published immediately but are set for moderation so I myself can say who gets in and who doesn't. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give anonymous users the permission to create content of that type. And you can set the default publishing setting to unpublished (They can't change that unless they have the required permission).

For the theming part, if you are using the admin theme for the node add/edit forms, then you'll have to disable it for that content type. You can do so with a bit of custom code and implement [hook_admin_paths()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7) and return `'node/add/content-type' => FALSE` path. This will override the definition in [node_admin_paths()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_admin_paths/7). Because for a path to be considered as an admin path, there needs to be an entry that returns TRUE and no entry that returns FALSE.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! But sorry you lost me at "For the theming part..." You see, I'm more of a designer than a developer so if possible, use small words. :-)

Comment: With theming part, I meant the fact that you want to use the normal theme when creating content of that type. That's all.

Comment: @enchance To implement that hook, just copy the example code to a custom module (google has enough tutorials, you can also ask a new question here on how to create that), change hook to "yourmodule" and return what I posted above instead of the two example lines.

Answer (score 0):

Get into user permission (example.com/admin/people/permissions)

Under the node module settings there would be all the content type and their access actions against anonymous users and authenticated.

This Role-Action permission grid will help you to fine tune on privileges to users.